# rails belongs_to same model twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a Task model (fields = description, soldier_id:integer, created_by:integer).

Now I automatically assign `created_by` to the soldier that creates a task, and I want to use the `soldier_id` for the soldier that must execute the task.
This way, `Task` belongs to `Solider` in 2 different fields at the same time. **How should it be done properly?** Now I have:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :soldier
end
```

and

```
class Soldier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :soldier
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: Soldier, foreign_key: :created_by
end

class Soldier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks

  # Optional -- I'm unclear if you want this too?
  has_many :created_tasks, class_name: Task, foreign_key: :created_by
end
```

The above implementation is OK. However, if you wish to stick within rails conventions (i.e. not need to manually specify a `foreign_key`), then you could call the database column `creator_id` instead of `created_by`.

Comment: perfect! additional thanks for the rails convention tip!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :soldier
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'Soldier', foreign_key: :created_by
end
```

Now, given a `task` object, you can use `task.creator` to retrieve the soldier you want